# Lotus notes workflow migration to SharePoint

Tags: c#, workflow, lotus-notes

I am new to lotus notes, so need help and suggestions.
Is there any way to access workflows from lotus notes?
Can we write any automated tool to migrate general lotus workflow to SharePoint directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I worked on Lotus Notes->Oracle Portal migration for a large customer, and then worked on building an intranet site using Sharepoint 2007 for the same customer.

There are plenty of commercial tools assisting you on migrating from Lotus to Sharepoint (this seems to be an almost inevitable process, unless you prefer to go for Liferay/Alfresco)... these tend to concentrate on migrating *documents* instead of workflow, though, and I we never found anything "free" that could really help in the migration.

What I can say is that rolling out your own converter is probably too much of a problem. If you have a few dozens workflows you would probably be better served by converting "by hand". If you are making a complete migration (including documents) I suggest you to look for commercial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow itself is not a part of built-in Notes functionality, so there's nothing that can be called "General Notes workflow". It is always built using third-party solutions or add-on like Lotus Workflow which is *not* part of Lotus Notes/Domino. But anyhow it doesn't seem to be possible for placing SharePoint list item or document in the middle of the flow as you want it. Let all running flows finish on Notes and migrate the historical data.